# Automatically expand excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatable

I am working on a model to predict UFC fights, and I am having an issue retrieving the information from 2 differents sheets in my file.

Basically want I am trying to do is to retrieve the information from the specific fighter whom could be in as a fighter 1 or fighter 2 column and pass it to a table as it is shown in the following image

[image]

I am already able to retrieve the rows from the specific fighter with the following formula:

```vb
=IF(ROWS($C$14:C14)<=$A$12,INDEX(Fights[Fighter 2],AGGREGATE(15,3,(Fights[Fighter 1] = $B$2) / (Fights[Fighter 1] = $B$2) * (ROW(Fights[Fighter 1]) - ROW(Fights[[#Headers],[Fighter 1]])),ROWS($C$14:C14))), "")
```

getting the outout shown in the picture [image]

However, I can not get the table to adjust to the amount of rows each fighter needs.

My goal is to be able to consolidate the 2 tables into one so I can get some insights from the fighter record

Comment: Post some copiable data using [Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) and show your expected output as well. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78114942/edit) the post and paste the copiable data as text.

Comment: Power query is likely the direction you'd want to head with this.

Answer (score 0):

Get/Transform the data into a query. (Highlight your input data and then, in the data ribbon, get and transform from table.

This should create a query and open a power Query editor window showing this query. In the power query editor window, in the first ribbon, click Manage - Reference to create a second query based on your first one. When you click "Advanced Editor" in the ribbon, it would look something like

```ml
let
    Source = Table1, // or whatever the first query is called
in
    Source
```

Change it to

```ml
let
    Source = Table1, // or whatever the first query is called
    StatColumnNames = List.RemoveNulls(
        List.Transform(
            Table.ColumnNanes(Source),
            each if Text.StartsWith(_, "Fighter_1_") then
              Text.Range(_, 10)
            else
              null
        )
    ),
    StatColumnValues = List.Transform(
        StatColumnNames,
        each Table.Column(Source, "Fighter_1_" & _) & Table.Column(Source, "Fighter_2_" & _)
    ),
    Locations = List.Repeat(
        Source[Location],
        2
    ),
    // I didn't see a column of fight dates. Is this missing?!? Fix or remove as appropriate
    Dates = List.Repeat(
        Source[Date],
        2
    ),
    Fighters = Source[#"Fighter 1"] & Source[#"Fighter 2"],
    Combined = Table.FromColumns(
        // Column values (a list of lists)
        {Locations, Dates, Fighters} & StatColumnValues,
        // Column titles (a text list)
        {"Location", "Date", "Fighter"} & StatColumnNames
    )
in
    Combined
```

This should give you a flat table per fight per fighter. Change the name of this query to whatever makes sense for you.

Closing the query editor and loading to your workbook should create a new tab containing a table of this data. This table will update when you refresh it using the data ribbon's "Refresh All" button.

You can then create a pivot table from this data allowing you to categorize by fighter, date, and location, then format the pivot table to your liking.